# What is the equivalent of GNU tm in visual studio?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, time, gnu

It seems that the definition of tm structure in GNU c and visual studio is different.

In GNU C, this structure holds time zone data but in visual studio it doesn't.

I am receiving time as tm structure from a Linux computer and I need to map a memory to get all of its data.

Is there any structure in visual studio for this that has the same memory footprint as tm in gnu?

I am trying to write that structure by myself but it seems that I am getting its size wrong. I am developing in win64, but the data comes from a 32 bit Linux machine.

What is the size of this structure in Linux?

Answer (score 5):

You should not send such memory-layout and system-sensitive structs as literal bytes over the network. Instead you should communicate the contents in a well-defined way, which you convert at both ends into something useful.

Comment: Thanks for your information. It is not over network, but it is on file. That only the two system can work.

Comment: Even so, @rubenvb is correct. Rather than writing the contents of tm directly to the file, you should use a more general format like JSON or XML to parcel up the data.

Comment: @adelphus JSON/XML is not really what I had in mind. A plain set of numbers or strings would do here. That is also easier to parse by yourself without resorting to a relatively huge library only to transfer data between two programs...

Comment: The problem is that I want to write and read them very fast. Relying on any other method required a lot of processing.

Comment: JSON is pretty small. And I kinda always advocate common formats over re-inventing the data serialisation wheel. You just never know who/what is going to use the data in the future...

Comment: @mans: the thing is, a future glibc update or even compiler update could change the in-memory representation of a C struct, which would screw up your code. Simple remedy: don't. You're not going to tell me reading [9 integers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html) is going to slow you down.

Comment: @rubenvb It is only part of the data that I am sending or receiving. The whole data is around 500K. I completely understand your point, but serializing such data with any library is much more time consuming than using plain memory map files. The problem is this structure which is different in Linux and windows. everything else is working properly. If I want to do things in C#, I would do it differently, but I am doing it in C/C++ for speed.

Comment: @mans I repeat: sending a struct which contains 9 integers or sending 9 integers will not significantly change the speed at which the operation happens. But if you don't want to hear it, I can't help you.